# Displaying local html pages on WebView

Tags: html, webview, jfxpanel

I am trying to display a html page using WebView in JFXpanel.
When I run the given code I get proper output i.e website("stack overflow") as mentioned in the load method.

```
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    webView.getEngine().load("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

But when I replace the link with a local html file it doesnt give the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {  
    try {  
        WebView web = new WebView();   
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");  
        path.replace("\\\\", "/");  
        path +=  "/html/index.html";  
        web.getEngine().load("file:///" + path);   
        Scene scene = new Scene(web, 400,400);   
        stage.setScene(scene);   
        stage.show();   
    } catch(Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3519040?start=0&tstart=0